# How to open new activity after camera intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-studio

So I wrote this code that starts camera intent when button is clicked after that it should open new activity but instead it just returns to main activity where camera button is. Here is my code:

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 2) {
                    Intent k = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FullActivity.class);
                    startActivity(k);
        }
    }
});
```

Can someone help me and show where the problem is. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your `onActivityResult()` to be a method on your `Activity`, not a method on your `OnClickListener`.

Also, you might add the `@Override` annotation to it, so the compiler yells at you when you have the method in the wrong spot, as is the case here.